# Is there any software for minimal-pair training?

Tags: anki, resource-request, minimal-pairs

Gabriel Wyner, in his book [*Fluent Forever*](http://amzn.to/1YtOusY), stresses the importance of [minimal pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) training early in the language learning process. He summarizes the research behind this suggestion in [this video](https://youtu.be/aPSvSYiGUfY).

His book details how to create these cards for use in [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/). He also makes some cards available on his web site in the form of "[Pronunciation Trainers](https://fluent-forever.com/bundles)", available or purchase (I've never used them, I cannot recommend them).

The problem I find is that Anki always presents the cards in a predictable order. This means that, given two sounds, A and B, I know I will always be presented with A first, then B. Even if I “try” to forget this, it’s impossible--especially for new cards, when I see the same set of cards 4 times in a row.

Also, after a few days, if I miss a review card, it will be even easier to cheat. Suppose I miss ‘A’. A moment later I come across ‘B’ and I know which one it is, and answer correctly, pushing that card forward for a month.

Now for the next month, every time I see that card, I know it’s ‘A’ without even listening to it.

Is anyone aware of a tool that overcomes this problem? I would be happy with a way to make Anki not behave this way, but I think this is a long shot. So another tool would be ideal (even one I pay for).

Comment: To the down-voter, care to explain what you think the problem is with the question, and ideally how it could be improved?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would say: 1. Part of it is promotional for a product for sale ("available for purchase"). It seems to be a recommendation. 2. Does the problem you mention (presents the cards in a predictable order) only occur when using the mentioned resources? If not, just describe the situation generically. 3. I think you can leave out the first two paragraphs. The rest explains the issue and the problem you are trying to resolve.

Comment: @user3169: The problem is specific to his style of "minimal pair" cards... this is why I provide the links, to give context (not to promote his products).

Comment: I have edited the question a bit to look less like an endorsement.

Comment: I find that claim a bit hard to believe, though... if I was trying to promote his product, why would I be asking for an alternative?

Comment: I've not noticed that Anki is very predictable. How long have you had this problem?

Comment: @Hatchet: Since I started trying to use minimal pair flashcards in Anki (~18 months ago?)

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [Support](http://ankisrs.net/docs/help.html) site on Anki? Also, since the card in Anki use HTML to display, you can try to find a way to show random object in HTML, though I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: @Ooker: With Javascript it would be, in theory, possible to show a random object in HTML, but there's no way to ensure that both random things are shown, and correctly selected, before advancing the card.

Answer (score 9):

Getting Anki to work with minimal pairs is tricky but possible. I will present
a card template with only one card that will choose a random word from
the minimum pair on each appearance of the card.
Since this is only one card, therefore there are no scheduling issues. I use it
for my own minimal pair training. The method works with the desktop client and
AnkiDroid.

1. If you are using a desktop client, then install [replay buttons addon](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/498789867).
2. Create a new card template with 4 fields: "First Sound", "First Word",
   "Second Sound", "Second Word". In the "Sound" fields you'll be putting the
   audio files. In the "Word" fields, you'll be putting their word
   descriptions, e.g. "knees /niːz/".
3. In the front template put the following text:

   ```
   <script>
   function persist(cb) {
     window.setTimeout(function() {
       // Determine whether to use Anki's Bridge object (Desktop) or sessionStorage (AnkiDroid) to store data across sides.
       // Note that sessionStorage can only store strings.
       var dummy = {};
       var mode = "dummy";
       if (typeof(py) !== "undefined") {
         mode = "py";
         py.data = py.data || {};
       } else if (typeof(sessionStorage) !== "undefined") {
         mode = "sessionStorage";
       }
       var dataObj = {
         setItem: function(key, val) {
           if (mode === "dummy") {
             dummy[key] = val;
           } else if (mode === "py") {
             py.data[key] = val;
           } else if (mode === "sessionStorage") {
             sessionStorage.setItem(key, val);
           }
         },
         getItem: function(key, def) {
           var val = undefined;
           if (mode === "dummy") {
             val = dummy[key];
           } else if (mode === "py") {
             val = py.data[key];
           } else if (mode === "sessionStorage") {
             val = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
           }
           if (val == null) {
             return def;
           } else {
             return val;
           }
         },
         tryItem: function(key, val) {
           var currVal = dataObj.getItem(key, undefined);
           if (currVal == null) {
             dataObj.setItem(key, val);
             return val;
           } else {
             return currVal;
           }
         },
         clear: function() {
           if (mode === "dummy") {
             dummy = {};
           } else if (mode === "py") {
             window.py.data = {};
           } else if (mode === "sessionStorage") {
             sessionStorage.clear();
           }
         }
       };

       if (!document.getElementById("back")) {
         dataObj.clear();
       }

       cb(dataObj, mode);
     }, 0); //Execute after Anki has loaded its Bridge object.
   }
   persist(function(data, mode) {
     var id = data.tryItem("which", Math.random() >= 0.5 ? "first" : "second");
     document.getElementById("front-" + id).style.display = "block";
     if (document.getElementById("back")) {
       document.getElementById("back-" + id).style.display = "block";
     }
   });
   </script>

   <div id="front">
   What word do you hear?<br>
   <span id="front-first" style="display: none">{{First Sound}}</span>
   <span id="front-second" style="display: none">{{Second Sound}}</span>
   </div>
   ```
4. In the back set the following

   ```
   {{FrontSide}}

   <hr id=answer>

   <div id="back">
   You have heard the word:
   <span id="back-first" style="display: none">{{First Word}}</span>
   <span id="back-second" style="display: none">{{Second Word}}</span>
   </div>

   <div id="note">You may practice both words again:<br/>
   {{First Word}} {{First Sound}}<br>
   {{Second Word}} {{Second Sound}}
   </div>
   ```
5. I use the following styling

   ```
   .card {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
   }

   #note {
     border-width: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
     border-style: solid;
     margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
     padding: 0px;
   }
   ```

Now you are ready to add new notes and train. This method is based on [this
excellent post](https://www.yingtongli.me/blog/2015/03/15/random-question-generator-on-anki-using.html).

Example of how it should look in practice:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Quizlet seems to be a good choice. By searching up "minimal pairs linguistics", you get a ton of flashcard decks to use [here](https://quizlet.com/subject/minimal-pairs-linguistics/).

In Quizlet, the cards are always randomized and there are many options to change the way the flashcards are to suit your learning style. For example, there are two different views, audio, a button used to shuffle, and a feature that changes what text is shown on the flashcard. Though Quizlet is not focused on linguistics, the site contains lots and lots of flashcards decks for linguistics. Even try to make you own to quiz yourself/keep track of what you know.

Answer (score 0):

Anki have an extensive card markup and single note transformed into several cards. You should create note with separate sounds and add 2 card types which differ by ordering of sound samples.

So you have fields `Word1`, `Word2`, `Sound1`, `Sound2` and two card types:

```
### Front:
{{Word1}} or {{Word2}}?
[sound:{{Sound1}}]

### Back:
{{FrontSide}}
<hr id=answer>
It's {{Word1}}!
```

and:

```
### Front:
{{Word1}} or {{Word2}}?
[sound:{{Sound2}}]

### Back:
{{FrontSide}}
<hr id=answer>
It's {{Word2}}!
```

There is option to shuffle notes. But usually cards start coming in delay of one day with Anki bury mechanic but with following increasing repetition intervals they would appear at random.

Please read manual http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#basic-templates

Comment: From the question: "The problem I find is that Anki always presents the cards in a predictable order."

Comment: You are **wrong to some extents**. If cards created from single note they will be shown on different days. http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#siblings-and-burying I've explained how to make two cards from single note.

Comment: They are shown on different days, but in a predictable order. This entirely defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Flimzy Anki can present cards in the order you entered them or in random order. Have you checked whether the "random order" option is active?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Random order only applies to the order of notes on a given day, and doesn't randomize which card you'll see from a given note.  This means that you will always get card 1 before card 2 of a given minimal pair. And worse, if you miss one, one half of the pair will be rescheduled and the other not. This leads to potentially weeks of review of only half the pair. Not meaningful random at all.