# anki minimal pairs

Tags: resource-request, anki, minimal-pairs

I'm looking for a way to practice minimal pairs with anki in a relatively  effective way. One of the problems I'm having is the minimal pair cards are not random enough. Also, the cards aren't shown enough.  I tried following this guide from this answer previously posted here: [Is there any software for minimal-pair training?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/393/is-there-any-software-for-minimal-pair-training) However, unfortunately it isn't working for me.

Has anyone followed this guide and gotten it to work?
And does anyone here use anki with minimal pairs? If so, what options do you use? If not, how do you go about studying minimal pairs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Both randmization and higher frequency can be adjusted in Anki. Please have a look [into the manual](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html) and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: Hi Cacambo, welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Please be aware that this is not a forum, so responses saying "come back if you still have questions" don't work very well here. You could significantly improve your answer by quoting or paraphrasing the essential information that you link to instead of merely providing a link.